# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when dynamically assigning value to matTooltip

Tags: angular, angular-material

When dynamically assigning value to `matTooltip` I get this error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.
I tried fixing it using `detectChanges()` but then I get this error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

**Requirement:** I need to show tooltip when text is truncated.

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
  <p *ngFor="let each of tooltipsData" #element [matTooltip]="isTextTruncated(element) ? each : null">{{each}}</p>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
tooltipsData = [
 "Lorem Ipsum",
 "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
 "Lorem",
 "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
];

isTextTruncated(element: any) {
 // this.cdr.detectChanges();
 return element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
}
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nhveu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR** - call `detectChanges()` in `ngAfterViewInit()`

**Example**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

> **Explanation**

Angular runs [list of lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) starting from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`. In this process angular stores previous values and compare with current value (e.g., In `ngOnInit` when `x` is `false` and in `ngAfterViewInit` `x` is `true`), when value is changed while `lifecycle hooks` are running then this error occurs `Expression...Previous value: 'message: false'. Current value: 'message: true'.`

> **My scenario**

I am displaying tooltip based on DOM manipulation (when text is truncated), So in `ngOnInit` no elements are loaded in DOM, So initially value is `null` and in `ngAfterViewInit` elements are loaded and tooltip value changed from `null` to `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text`. **So we need to tell angular to detect changes in** `ngAfterViewInit`.

**Other Scenario** [Async API](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/)

> **Update**

The above solution works in **example stackblitz**, but in **my real angular project** it doesn't work because I get tooltip value from **Async API**.

> So I called `detectChanges()` after API is completed.